# Connecting a Range Expander to a Home Wireless Router

Tags: router, ip-address

I'm trying to connect a Cisco Range Expander WRE54G to a Wireless Router ZXHN F618.

I use Windows 10 on HP laptop, and Chrome as my default browser.

The wireless router has the standard N, whereas the Range Expander has the standard G, but I enabled mixed mode on my router so I don't think that should be a problem.

I ran the 192.168.1.240 IP address in the address bar, which is supposedly the IP address of my range expander, but it said: "This site can't be reached". Also, I ran the ping command too, and I received four responses saying: "This host is unreachable", from the IP address of my laptop.

I checked the routing table from my router on my laptop, and it came to my surprise that despite all the other connected devices appeared ( except for the expander, which is apparently not connected), my laptop's IP didn't show.

I did everything I read in the range expander's manual, but I don't think my laptop and my router respectively would recognize but what if it has another IP address?? Which, if the case, would be really odd since I never set the expander up before.

Comment: It needs unsecured Wireless to make a connection. Use an Ethernet Connection to set it up.   https://www.linksys.com/us/support-article/?articleNum=133319

Comment: The article says: "Using an Ethernet cable, connect the range expander to the computer.  This will enable you to access its web-based setup page." . I tried to connect them with a super healthy ethernet cable, on both the reset mode and autoconfiguration mode, but when I type in in the address bar the ip address of the range expander ( 192.168.1.240 ), it's unreachable. Any other tips?

Comment: If the device is new, contact the vendor support. It appears it might not be working properly. Ethernet is very easy to connect and make a connection. Your own cable is likely good, same for the Ethernet port on your computer. So if that does not work, it indicates a hardware issue of some kind.